# How can i apply nested string operators in projection?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to create an implementation using aggregator framework that executes this projection:

```
{ $project : { code: $toUpper : { $substr : ["$vendor", 0, 2 ] } } }
```

So far I have not found a way to express the concatenation of the `$substr` and `$toUpper` operation using Spring. I have tried with this construction and other similar variants, but I have not succeeded.

```
ProjectionOperation projection = project()
                .and("vendor").substring(0, 2).toLower().as("code");
```

Can anyone give me an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
project()
    .and(ToLower.lowerValueOf(SubstrCP.valueOf("vendor").substringCP(0, 2)))
    .as("code")
```